ngx-image-viewer : Image not getting dragged properly. Dragging the image makes the application unresponsive
I'm using ngx-image-viewer in an Angular 15 application, where I'm showing single image.
The ngx-image-viewer plugin has a default drag feature.
In my case the image is getting dragged but the drag action is extremely slow and image stutters while dragging. Until this drag operation is not completed the application remains unresponsive.
Plugin
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-viewer
